# String parsing in C

Tags: c, strings, parsing

This is supposed to be strict ANSI C89 pedantic code. It should extract `word1`, `word2` and `word3` from a string formatted [ word1 ] word2 [ word3 ] and return failure in any other format.

It seems to work, but it seems so ugly. No need to comment about the fact `GetTokenBetweenSquareBraces` and `GetTokenBtweenOpositeSquareBraces` are duplicates.

I would love some tips on how to clean this up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * TrimWhiteSpaces(char *str) {
    char *out = str;
    int i;
    int len = strlen(str);
    for (i=0; i<len && isspace(str[i]); i++, out++); /*scan forward*/
    for (i=len-1; i>=0 && isspace(str[i]); str[i]=0, i--);/*scan backward*/
    return out;
}
char * GetTokenBetweenSquareBraces(char * input, char **output, int * output_size) {
    char *p = TrimWhiteSpaces(input);
    *output_size=0;
    if (p[0] == '[')
    {
        *output = TrimWhiteSpaces(p + 1);
        do       
        {                
            (*output_size)++;        
        }while((*output)[*output_size] != ']' && isalnum((*output)[*output_size]));
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    return (*output) + *output_size;
}
char * GetTokenBtweenOpositeSquareBraces(char * input, char **output, int * output_size) {
    char *p = TrimWhiteSpaces(input);
    *output_size=0;
    if (p[0] == ']')
    {
        *output = TrimWhiteSpaces(p + 1);
        do       
        {                
            (*output_size)++;        
        }while((*output)[*output_size] != '[' && isalnum((*output)[*output_size]));
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    return (*output) + *output_size;
}
int GetWords(char * str,char * word1,char * word2,char * word3)
{
    char * next=NULL,*output=NULL;

    int outputsize;
    printf ("\nSplitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);

    next = GetTokenBetweenSquareBraces (str,&output,&outputsize);
    strncpy(word1,output,outputsize);
    word1[outputsize] = '\0';
    strcpy(word1,TrimWhiteSpaces(word1));
    if(!next) return 0;

    next = GetTokenBtweenOpositeSquareBraces (next,&output,&outputsize);
    strncpy(word2,output,outputsize);
    word2[outputsize] = '\0';
    strcpy(word2,TrimWhiteSpaces(word2));

    if(!next) return 0;

    next = GetTokenBetweenSquareBraces (next,&output,&outputsize);
    strncpy(word3,output,outputsize);
    word3[outputsize] = '\0';
    strcpy(word3,TrimWhiteSpaces(word3));

    if(!next) return 0;

    return 1;
}
void TestGetWords(char * str )
{
    char word1[20],word2[20],word3[20];
    if (GetWords(str,word1,word2,word3))
    {
        printf("|%s|%s|%s|\n",word1,word2,word3);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("3ViLLLL\n");
    }

}
int main (void)
{
    char str[] ="[  hello   ]  gfd   [ hello2 ] ";
    char str2[] ="[ hello   [  gfd   [ hello2 ] ";
    char str3[] ="the wie321vg42g42g!@#";
    char str4[] ="][123[]23][231[";

    TestGetWords(str);
    TestGetWords(str2);
    TestGetWords(str3);
    TestGetWords(str4);
    getchar();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: First off fix your indentation. Markdown engine doesn't like tabs - replace them with spaces.

Comment: @LokiAstari: it looks like you replaced his original code.

Comment: Opps. Sorry. Fixed my screw up I hope. I got the code from the article on meta. fixed the tab problem and put it back. If this is not correct I am sorry, but I can't seem to rollback a version.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Yep, looks a lot better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * TrimWhiteSpaces(char *str) {
    char *out = str;
    int i;
    int len = strlen(str);
    for (i=0; i<len && isspace(str[i]); i++, out++); /*scan forward*/
```

I'd at least have a body with a comment in it here. Its easy to miss that semicolon. I don't think you need the `i < len` test. The 0 at the end of the string should fail the `isspace` test and so you don't need to check for the length as well. It also doesn't really make sense to keep track of `i`. Instead, just use `out`.

```
    for (i=len-1; i>=0 && isspace(str[i]); str[i]=0, i--);/*scan backward*/
```

It isn't really necessary to set all those spaces to 0. Overall, you are doing to much work in that one line. You should at least only do the 0 setting inside the loop body because it has nothing to do with the loop control.

```
    return out;
```

Generally, its best to either modify your parameters or return new ones. Don't do both. Here you return a new string pointer and modify the original string.

```
}
char * GetTokenBetweenSquareBraces(char * input, char **output, int * output_size) {
    char *p = TrimWhiteSpaces(input);
    *output_size=0;
    if (p[0] == '[')
    {
        *output = TrimWhiteSpaces(p + 1);
        do       
        {                
            (*output_size)++;        
        }while((*output)[*output_size] != ']' && isalnum((*output)[*output_size]));
```

`]` isn't a number or a letter. You don't need both of these tests.

```
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    return (*output) + *output_size;
}

char * GetTokenBtweenOpositeSquareBraces(char * input, char **output, int * output_size)        {
    char *p = TrimWhiteSpaces(input);
    *output_size=0;
    if (p[0] == ']')
    {
        *output = TrimWhiteSpaces(p + 1);
        do       
        {                
            (*output_size)++;        
        }while((*output)[*output_size] != '[' && isalnum((*output)[*output_size]));
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    return (*output) + *output_size;
}
```

Deja Vu! This is almost exactly the same as the previous function. Only the bracket directions have been reversed. It seems that you should be able to share that code.

```
int GetWords(char * str,char * word1,char * word2,char * word3)
{
    char * next=NULL,*output=NULL;

    int outputsize;
    printf ("\nSplitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
```

Generally I recommend against having your working functions doing any output. Also odd choice of where to put newlines.

```
    next = GetTokenBetweenSquareBraces (str,&output,&outputsize);
    strncpy(word1,output,outputsize);
    word1[outputsize] = '\0';
    strcpy(word1,TrimWhiteSpaces(word1));
```

Why are you trimming whitespace here? Didn't you already do that. You are doing a lot of work to copy the text. Maybe that's something that GetTokenBetweenSquareBraces should have done?

```
    if(!next) return 0;

    next = GetTokenBtweenOpositeSquareBraces (next,&output,&outputsize);
    strncpy(word2,output,outputsize);
    word2[outputsize] = '\0';
    strcpy(word2,TrimWhiteSpaces(word2));

    if(!next) return 0;
```

Deja Vu!

```
    next = GetTokenBetweenSquareBraces (next,&output,&outputsize);
    strncpy(word3,output,outputsize);
    word3[outputsize] = '\0';
    strcpy(word3,TrimWhiteSpaces(word3));

    if(!next) return 0;
```

Deja Vu!

```
    return 1;
}
void TestGetWords(char * str )
{
    char word1[20],word2[20],word3[20];
```

Your code isn't careful to make sure that you don't overflow these variables. You may want to do something about that

```
    if (GetWords(str,word1,word2,word3))
    {
        printf("|%s|%s|%s|\n",word1,word2,word3);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("3ViLLLL\n");
    }

}
int main (void)
{
    char str[] ="[  hello   ]  gfd   [ hello2 ] ";
    char str2[] ="[ hello   [  gfd   [ hello2 ] ";
    char str3[] ="the wie321vg42g42g!@#";
    char str4[] ="][123[]23][231[";

    TestGetWords(str);
    TestGetWords(str2);
    TestGetWords(str3);
    TestGetWords(str4);
```

For purposes of automated testing, its actually better if you provide the correct answer and check against that in code. That way the program will tell you when its wrong.

```
    getchar();
    return 1;
```

0 is used to indicate a successful program run.

```
}
```

Overall, your program is ugly because you are using the wrong vocabulary. You've taken the vocabulary as given instead of defining the vocabulary that made the task easy to describe.
Here is my approach to your problem

```
char * Whitespace(char * str)
/*
This function return the `str` pointer incremented past any whitespace.
*/
{
    /* when an error occurs, we return NULL.
    If an error has already occurred, just pass it on */
    if(!str) return str;

    while(isspace(*str))
    {
        str++;
    }
    return str;
}

char * Character(char * str, char c)
/*
This function tries to match a specific character.
It returns `str` incremented past the character
or NULL if the character was not found
*/
{
    if(!str) return str;
    /* Eat any whitespace before the character */ 
    str = Whitespace(str);

    if(c != *str)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        return str + 1;
    }
}

char * Word(char * str, char * word)
/*
This function reads a sequence of numbers and letter into word
and then returns a pointer to the position after the word
*/
{
    /* Handle errors and whitespace */
    if(!str) return str;
    str = Whitespace(str);

    /* copy characters */
    while(isalnum(*str))
    {
        *word++ = *str++;
    }
    *word = 0; /* don't forget null!*/
    return str;
}


int GetWords(char * str,char * word1,char * word2,char * word3)
{
    str = Character(str, '[');
    str = Word(str, word1);
    str = Character(str, ']');
    str = Word(str, word2);
    str = Character(str, '[');
    str = Word(str, word3);
    str = Character(str, ']');
    str = Character(str, '\0');
    return str != NULL;
}
```

What I've done (or tried to do) is write the Character, Whitespace, and Word functions such that they are really very simple. If you understand `char *` you shouldn't have any trouble with them. But these simple tools combine very nicely to allow a straightforward implementation of your parser.

Comment: +1 for "Generally I recommend against having your working functions doing any output".  Also, very nice and clean solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is perhaps a little less ugly, but string handling is never going to be pretty in C.

```
static const char * skip_space(const char *s)
{
    return s + strspn(s, " ");
}

static const char * skip_bracket(const char * s, int bracket)
{
    s = skip_space(s);
    if (*s != bracket)
        return NULL;

    return skip_space(++s);
}

static const char * skip_word(const char * s)
{
    return s + strcspn(s, " []");
}

static const char * copy_word(char *w, const char *s, size_t size)
{
    const char * end = skip_word(s);
    size_t len = end - s;
    if (len >= size) /* silently truncate word to buffer size */
        len = size - 1;

    memcpy(w, s, len);
    w[len] = '\0';
    return skip_space(end);
}

static int get_words(const char *s, char *w1, char *w2, char *w3, size_t size)
{
    if ((s = skip_bracket(s, '[')) == NULL)
        return 0;

    s = copy_word(w1, s, size);

    if ((s = skip_bracket(s, ']')) == NULL)
        return 0;

    s = copy_word(w2, s, size);

    if ((s = skip_bracket(s, '[')) == NULL)
        return 0;

    s = copy_word(w3, s, size);

    if ((s = skip_bracket(s, ']')) == NULL)
        return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state machine to complete this task,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void Tokenize(char* s)
{
// the following array return new state based on current state and current scanned char
    //                          Input:         * [  ] space   Print     Tokenize        Current State   Expression                         
/*Next state:*/char StateArray[12][3][4] =  {{{11,1,11,0}   ,{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}  },    //0             {space}*{[}
                                             {{2,11,11,1}   ,{1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}},      //1             {space}*{char}
                                             {{2,11,4,3}    ,{1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0}},      //2             {char}*{space}?{]}
                                             {{11,11,4,3}   ,{0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0}},      //3             {space}*{]}
                                             {{5,11,11,4}   ,{1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}},      //4             {space)*{char}
                                             {{5,7,11,6}    ,{1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0}},      //5             {char}*{space}?{[}
                                             {{11,7,11,6}   ,{0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0}},      //6             {space}*{[}
                                             {{8,11,11,7}   ,{1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}},      //7             {space}*{char}
                                             {{8,11,10,9}   ,{1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0}},      //8             {char}*{space}?{]}
                                             {{11,11,10,9}  ,{0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0}},      //9             {space}*{]}
                                             {{11,11,11,10} ,{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}},      //10            {space}*
                                             {{11,11,11,11} ,{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}}
                                         };
char state=0;
int len = strlen(s);
for(int i =0;i<len;i++)
{
 if(StateArray[state][1][(s[i]^91)? ((s[i]^93)?((s[i]^32)? 0:3):2):1])
    printf("%c",s[i]);
if(StateArray[state][2][(s[i]^91)? ((s[i]^93)?((s[i]^32)? 0:3):2):1])
    printf("\n");
 state=StateArray[state][0][(s[i]^91)? ((s[i]^93)?((s[i]^32)? 0:3):2):1];
 switch(state)
 {
 case 11:
  printf("Error at column %d",i);
 case 10:
  if(i==len-1)
  {
    printf("\nParsing completed");
  }
}
}
}
int main(void)
{           
    char* s= " [ word1 ]  word2word [  3 ]   "; // test string
    Tokenize(s);
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Code Review. This code is not really a review. Rather, it is an alternate way of doing things with little explanation as to what it does, why it works, and why it is better than the original. Additionally, I look through it and worry about missing braces, fall-through case-statements, and obscure bitwise manipulations that are not documented. Please consider adding detail as to why this is better, and what it solves differently to the OP, and why those choices make for better code.

Comment: Did you create this by hand or is there some tool involved?   I like the concept but I'd be terrified of supporting this.  There are so many magic numbers.